# How do you find this limit with a relationship to $e$ using Taylor series?

Tags: calculus, limits, taylor-expansion, power-series, limits-without-lhopital

The limit in question is

$$
\lim_{x \to 0}\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right)^{1/x^2}
$$

When I replace $\sin(x)$ with its Taylor series about $0$ and cancel out the $x$, I get

$$
\lim_{x \to 0}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{6} + \frac{x^4}{5!} \mp \cdots\right)^{1/x^2}
$$

The answer in the book is $e^\frac{-1}{6}$. If I only look at the $x^2$ term, I can see where $-1/6$ comes from. I'm just not sure how I can definitively say the answer is $e^\frac{-1}{6}$. Why can I discount the other powers of $x$?

Comment: If you take the log, $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x^2} \log \left( \frac{\sin x}{x} \right) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x^2} \log \left( 1- \frac{x^2}{6} + o(x^2) \right) = \cdots$$ and you use the usual limit $$\lim_{y \to 0} \frac{\log y}{y}=1$$

Answer (score 2):

To handle the higher power terms, you can use the [big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Note that
$$
\frac{\sin x}{x}=\frac1x\left(x-\frac{x^3}{6}+O(x^5)\right)=1-\frac{x^2}{6}+O(x^4)
$$
and
$$
\ln(1-y)=-y-\frac{y^2}{2}-\frac{y^3}{3}+O(y^5)
$$
So
$$
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^{1/x^2}
=&\exp\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\ln(\frac{\sin x}{x})\right)\\
=&\exp\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\ln(1-\frac{x^2}{6}+O(x^4))\right)\\
=&\exp\left(\frac{1}{x^2}(-\frac{x^2}{6}+O(x^4))\right)\\
=&\exp\left(-\frac{1}{6}+O(x^2)\right)\to e^{-1/6}
\end{align}
$$
as $x\to 0$.

Comment: Note that it is also possible to use $\ln(1+y)$ with $y=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}-1$ instead of $\ln(1-y)$ with $y=1-\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$. (Also sorry about my last comment, I got tripped up by you using $\ln(1-x)$ instead of $\ln(1+x)$.)

Comment: @Ian: Thanks for the comment. I missed a ")" in the earlier version.

Comment: The reason for using $\ln(1-y)$ is that I find integrating the geometric series of $\frac{1}{1-y}$ easier than that of $\frac{1}{1+y}$ in my head because I don't need to worry about the signs... `:)`